# opengl fit an arbitrary shape

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm new to opengl. As a learning exercise I started manually building some basic shapes, then moved to writing a generic .off file viewer.

My question is how "size" the "window" to fit arbitrarily sized models. I had been trying to "pull back" from the model by translating in the -z direction by some factor based on the range of x, y, or z coords, and this works, usually, but not always and seems like the wrong approach. sorry for the quotes, like i said i'm new and am lacking some terminology.

This happens to be on an android platform using opengl es 1.0 if that makes a difference.

Can anyone point me to a best practice for achieving this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fit 3d model inside a window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180289/fit-3d-model-inside-a-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get familiar with the OpenGL functions for setting of your view volume/frustum.

Here's an [article specific to OpenGL ES (iPhone)](http://www.iphonemobilephones.com/opengl-es-from-the-ground-up-part-3-viewports-in-perspective.html) that should get you started, however the standard OpenGL programming guide and references both apply for these concepts, too.

Comment: i don't think that's the issue. i'm already setting up the view port as they do in the article. the problem is that i'm either too close to the model, or inside the model, or the model is simply too big for the view port. had been handling that by translating the model in the -z direction. the view port is already set to the size of the screen so i can't make that any bigger. can the view port be scaled?

Comment: Got it - in that case, you probably should look into using gluLookAt to set up your "camera" and read up on the ModelView matrix - here's a good FAQ for starting: http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm

Answer (score 0):

For achieving a Fit-to-window for all the objects in the viewer, you must first know the extents of all the objects -- xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin and zmax. Usually a Bounding Sphere is pre-calculated for all the individual objects and every time an object is added to the viewer, its bounding sphere is added/included to the existing global bounding sphere. That means, there is initially a bounding sphere for the viewer with a radius if 1 and centered at x0, y0 z0. Every time a new object is added to the viewer, its pre-calculated bounding sphere is added to the viewer. By adding, I mean updating the initial sphere's center and radius so that it envelops/contains the new one and thus growing the global one to accomodate the new spheres.  Once this is done, whenever the user issues the command for a fit, the camera will be positioned to the center of the sphere and the range values of the glOrtho will be updated to the radius of the sphere. Note, when new shperes are added, the center of the global sphere also will change since objects will be located apart and adding their spheres will produce a new sphere with a larger radius and different center. This method will not give an exact fit according to the different view projections (top, front, left etc.). If you want to have a more precise fit in different projections you need to have a BoundingBox instead of the sphere but the calculations involve a lot of projections and offset calculations an is more cumbersome.